# What is the cllable name for gams studio in Ubuntu terminal to launch it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, optimization, gams-math

I know my question is cheap but I really need your helps and I appreciate all who give tips to me.  I recently installed Gams for optimization purposes through this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mx_tYI3wyP4) and it was successful. I desire to use gams studio but I can not lauch it. Unfortunately, I am new to Ubuntu and I just know that to run an application, I should type its name in command line and hit the Enter but it dose not work to me. When I run gams in my terminal I get the followings which show my installation is perfect:

```
(base) amir@amir-ThinkPad-T420:~$ gams
--- Job ? Start 02/23/20 13:03:05 30.2.0 r482c588 LEX-LEG x86 64bit/Linux
*** 
*** GAMS Base Module 30.2.0 r482c588 Released Feb 07, 2020 LEG x86 64bit/Linux    
*** 
*** GAMS Development Corporation
*** 2751 Prosperity Ave, Suite 210
*** Fairfax, VA 22031, USA
*** +1 202-342-0180, +1 202-342-0181 fax
*** support@gams.com, www.gams.com
*** 
*** GAMS Release     : 30.2.0 r482c588 LEX-LEG x86 64bit/Linux
*** Release Date     : Released Feb  7, 2020
*** To use this release, you must have a valid license file for
*** this platform with maintenance expiration date later than
*** Jan 10, 2020
*** System Directory : /opt/gams30.2_linux_x64_64_sfx/
***
*** License          : /opt/gams30.2_linux_x64_64_sfx/gamslice.txt
*** GAMS Demo license for Amir Baghban             G200221|0002CO-GEN
*** Amir Kabir University of Technology, Holy See                    
*** DL00258400 **GAMS Demo license restricted to non-commercial use**
*** amirbaghban87@gmail.com, Amir Baghban                            
***
*** Licensed platform                             : Generic popular platforms
*** The installed license is valid.
*** Evaluation expiration date (GAMS base module) : Feb 15, 2021
*** Note: For solvers, other expiration dates may apply.
*** Run gamslib model licememo for more details.
*** Status: Normal completion
--- Job ? Stop 02/23/20 13:03:05 elapsed 0:00:00.001
```

Now I want to use gams studio to code. I read in its documentation page that gams studio is installed during gams installation and moreover, my Ubuntu 18.04 has glibc 2.29 as well as FUSE as necessary versions for gams studio. But I can not launch it through command line.

Comment: `$ gams studio` means: run gams to solve the model studio. Instead, look for an executable called `studio`.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thank you for your helpful comment. So, I want to go edit my question to the exact one concerning with studio's cllable name.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I got the answer from Gams forum. They recommended me to use file manager and find AppImage. Now I have access to Gams Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a bash alias for you. Add something like

```
alias gams_studio='~/path/to/gams/installation/studio/studio.AppImage'
```

to your .bashrc. Then you can start by invoking `gams_studio` in your shell.

Make sure the file studio.AppImage has the execution flag. You can set it via `chmod +x staudio.AppImage` if needed.